# How to keep pod in pending state until secret appears

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I'm trying to keep a pod be in pending state until the required secrets appear in the namespace.

Initially, I thought that if I made secret optional=false it would work, but it didn't.
From my point, a pod should be in pending state because there is a container that doesn't have all the resources it requires. But somehow it crashes because of the absence of the secret.

Example:

```
  volumes:
  - name: secret-volume
    secret:
      secretName: mysecret
      optional: false
```

Basically, I'm waiting for the specific secret (I know the name of the secret) and I want to keep my pod in a pending state, so it will start immediately when the secret will be created.

I know that it might be easier with help, but we do not use it. Is there any way how to do it?

Comment: It will try to start until the secret is there.

Comment: So what can you see in the events of such `Pod` when you `kubectl describe` it ?